# Open graph story friend tags, rename "with" preposition

Tags: facebook-opengraph

When I create an open graph story and tag friends in it, the story ends up looking like this:

A did action - with B.

Can I rename the "with" preposition to something else? In my case, I'd like it to say:

A added an object - from B.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople) says....

> There may be scenarios where your users will want to indicate that
>   they took an action with friends. This can be easily accomplished by
>   specifying the tags optional parameter when publishing a story.

So tagging people is not something to describe "USER_A received OBJECT from USER_B" or something, but to indicate the occasion that USER_A is/was actually *WITH* USER_B physically or virtually.

Also the document says...

> You can only encourage users to tag friends who are actually with them
>   as the action takes place. Therefore the proper use of this is to
>   indicate the user is actually with these friends when the action
>   occurred.

Maybe you are going to have to reconsider the use of Open Graph action.